# How efficiently generate unique pairs of values from a Pandas data frame with different indexes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe as:

```
+--------+------+
|numbers1|words1|
+--------+------+
|       1| word1|
|       1| word2|
|       2| word3|
|       3| word4|
|       3| word5|
+--------+------+
```

I want to produce another data frame that would generate all unique pairs of words in each group with different IDs. So the result for the above would be:

```
wordA    wordB
word1    word3
word1    word4
word1    word5
word2    word3
word2    word4
word2    word5
word3    word4
word3    word5
```

Comment: You mean all permutations?

Comment: No. Just those with different IDs as I presented in example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the above answer by @TonyTang works perfectly, but it is using python `itertools` (and not vectorized solution that improves looping in python),

I found a faster implementation using `numpy` and `pandas` :

Implementation:

```
def find_unique_perms_vectorized(df):
    df_size = df['words1'].shape[0]
    ind = np.array(np.triu_indices(df_size, 1)).T
    words = df['words1'].values[ind]
    nums = df['numbers1'].values[ind]
    words = words[np.where(nums[:,0]!=nums[:,1])]
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(words,columns='wordA wordB'.split())
    return new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comparison (note that i removed the `sort` inside the first example to provide faster implementation):

```
def find_unique_perms(df):
    combs = list(combinations(df['numbers1'].unique(), 2))
    refs = df.groupby(['numbers1'])['words1'].agg(list).to_dict()
    results = [] 
    for a, b in combs:
        for x in refs[a]:
            for y in refs[b]:
                results.append((x, y))

    return pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['wordA', 'wordB']).reset_index(drop=True)

def find_unique_perms_vectorized(df):
    df_size = df['words1'].shape[0]
    ind = np.array(np.triu_indices(df_size, 1)).T
    words = df['words1'].values[ind]
    nums = df['numbers1'].values[ind]
    words = words[np.where(nums[:,0]!=nums[:,1])]
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(words,columns='wordA wordB'.split())
    return new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

after timing it in the following dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers1': np.random.randint(1,100,(1000)), 'words1': ['word' +str(i) for i in range(1000)]})
```

Vectorized implementation About (8 times faster):

```
%timeit find_unique_perms_vectorized(df) : 45.3 ms ± 3.52 ms
```

@TonyTang answer:

```
%timeit find_unique_perms(df) :  377 ms ± 8.38 ms
```

Note: please inform me if further explaination on the implementation is needed

Comment: This was the efficient that I was looking for! Beautiful solution.

Answer (score 4):

you can simply do something like this, given that time is not a concern.

```
import pandas as pd 
from itertools import combinations
 
df = pd.DataFrame({'number1': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3], 'words1': ['word1', 'word2', 
'word3', 'word4', 'word5']})
```

first find all combination by ID groups,

```
combs = list(combinations(df['number1'].unique(), 2))

# to refers what words in a group
refs = df.groupby(['number1'])['words1'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

then for each combination at group level, find all combination of words

```
results = [] 
for a, b in combs:
    for x in refs[a]:
        for y in refs[b]:
            results.append((x, y))

results = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['wordA', 'wordB']).sort_values('wordA')
```

Comment: Its a nice answer but i feel that there is a way to vectorize it with way faster implementations using numpy and pandas... ( +1 from me too)